# Keeping user logged into website using PHP POST without form

Tags: php

How do I keep the user logged into my website when they switch pages using PHP POST without a form?

Maybe like this (I am aware that this code might be a little crazy):

```
<?php
  define (php_post_request, (name), (Werling));
  header ('Location: ' . $_GET["location"], php_post_request);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One option is sessions and have session_start(); at top of each page. You should read the PHP basics on `php.net`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use sessions.

You start a session by using session_start(); which allows you to access the SESSIONS superglobal.

After successful sign up, set a SESSION variable for their user ID (in the simplest of cases). The pages that require a user to be logged in would then retain this information across the pages, you just check for the existence and value of the variable.

See here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: It does it until the session is destroyed, or it expires. You can destroy on logout using session destroy, or just unset that particular variable, i.e. unset($_SESSION['userid']).

Comment: Guys, why you gotta be so rude? Don't you know I'm human too? I'm gonna post it anyway. But seriously, all this vitriol about w3schools is slightly tiring, it's not a brilliant resource, but it's not like you're going to kill your website by using it occasionally.

Comment: I'll use sessions and W3Schools.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start a session once the user logs in and on every other page the user has access to, and make sure it's the very first method on each page.  Then, pass the information into a $_SESSION variable.  For instance, on the login page:

**Login page**

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["id"] = $user_id;
}
```

**Landing page**

```
<?php
session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION["user"];
    echo $username;
?>
```

Comment: Note session_start() needs to be above your creation of `$_SESSION["id"]`

Comment: Yep, completely forgot to add that.  Answer has been corrected.

Comment: Actually it's a good practice to set session_start() in beginning of file,

Comment: Even if the session hasn't been started and the user still hasn't logged in, should the session still be started though?  I've always been under the impression that you don't want to start the session until it's required.  Is that wrong?